# Which force is necessary for providing centripetal force to a rotating gyroscope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gyroscopes

When a gyroscope is precessing around an axis due to a certain applied torque, if we look at the center of mass , it is going around in circular motion. So there must be some force which provides the necessary centripetal force? What is this force?
[image: Bicycle Wheel Gyroscope]

If it is the tension that is producing this force shouldnt the string be inclined at an angle instead of being vertical.

[image]

And in this case is it really friction that provides the centripetal force?

Comment: In the case of your bicycle wheel, it's torque resulting from the horizontal offset between the center of mass of the wheel and the point on the wheel at which the wheel is suspended from above.

Comment: That is all right, but if we consider the object to be a point object placed at it's centre of mass, it is executing circular motion and therefore, requires a centripetal force. Who provides it.

Comment: You can't look at rotational behaviors using a point mass. Point masses don't exhibit rotational behaviors, at least not in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: If you are familiar with the motion of a Gyroscope you will agree that the centre of mass moves in a circular path with omega precession. Newton's laws mandate that there be a centripetal force equal to m x omega^2 x R who provides this force.